# Oracle explain plan over simple select performs multiple hash joins when multiple columns are indexed in a table

Tags: performance, oracle, database-design, data-warehouse

I am currently running into an issue with my Oracle instance.  I have two simple select statements:

```
select * from dog_vets
```

and

```
select * from dog_statuses
```

and the following [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37754)

My explain plan on `dog_vets` is as follows:

```
 0 | Select Statement  
 1 | Table Access Full Scan dog_vets
```

my explain plan on `dog_statuses`  is as follows:

```
ID|Operation | Name | Rows |Bytes | cost | time    
0 | Select Statement |  | 20G | 500M | 100000 | 999:99:17  
1 | View  | index%_join_001 | 20G | 500M | 100000 | 999:99:17  
2 | Hash Join  |  | | | |   
3 | Hash Join  |  | | | |   
4 | Index fast full scan dog_statuses_check_up  |  | 20G | 500M | 100000 | 32:15:00  
5 | Index fast full scan dog_statuses_sick|  | 20G | 500M | 100000 | 35:19:00
```

To get this type of output execute the following statement:

```
explain plan for   
select * from dog_vets;
```

OR

```
 explain plan for   
    select * from dog_statuses;
```

and then

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

Now my question is, why do multiple indexes imply a view (materialized  I assume) being created in my above statements and further what type of performance hit am I suffering on this type of query?  As it stands now `dog_vets` has ~300 million records and `dog_Statuses` has about 500 million.  I have yet to be able to get `select * from dog_statuses` to return in under 10 hours.  This is primarily because the query dies before it completes.

**DDL**

In case sql fiddle dies:

```
create table dog_vets
(
     name varchar2(50),
     founded timestamp,
     staff_count number
  );

create table dog_statuses
(
      check_up timestamp,
      sick varchar2(1)
  );


create index dog_vet_name
on dog_vets(name);

create index dog_status_check_up
on dog_statuses(check_up);

create index dog_status_sick
on dog_statuses(sick);
```

Comment: Are you sure `dog_statuses` is a table? Maybe it is indeed a view. What does `select object_type from all_objects where object_name = 'DOG_STATUSES';` return?

Comment: It returns table on my database.

Comment: Can you show the **full** execution plan? Btw: what do you plan to do with the 500 million rows that you retrieve? You can't possibly keep them in memory or display them to the user.

Comment: By full execution plan you mean the cost and such?  The 500 million rows are getting pushed into a materialized view that gets refreshed every X minutes based on things that occur on the system

Comment: I'm talking about the details for each step. If `DOG_STATUSES` is indeed a table, then there must be a reason for that, and that can only be seen with a detailed and complete execution plan.

Comment: Updated my table for completeness.

Comment: If there are only two columns in dog_statuses, do you think the optimizer might be trying to read values from the indexes instead of from data pages?

Comment: @Catcall it very well could be attempting to do that, the issue is it generates a lot of extra joins which in turn make the generation of my materialized view near impossible.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Can you edit your question and paste in the SQL DDL for dog_vets and dog_statuses?

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Is that from your production database? No primary keys, no foreign keys, etc?

Comment: @Catcall it is from a test system, if you want I can update it to include a specific PK, but there are no FKs.  i omitted the extra hash join that occurred with the PK,

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I think what we want is more confidence that the code we look at is actually the code that's causing the problem. Personally, I'd like to see the SQL DDL for dog_vets and dog_statuses *pasted from the production system*. That word *pasted* is important. Also, tell us what version of Oracle is in use on the system that's causing the problem.

Comment: @Catcall if i could paste it i would but i can't, i have to hand transcribe it.  The generation of explain plan is reproducible, which is the heart of the question.

Comment: If you have a regular table of 500 mil rows that a simple select * from doesn't return, it sounds like you have some other problem. Have you engaged a DBA?

Comment: It isnt a regular table that needs a select *,  it is a series of intricate joins, which is why i am using mat views.

Comment: The statistics look wrong to me.  How can there be 20 billion rows but only 500MB?  Were these statistics manually set?  And the time seems ridiculously high, I wonder if you're running into the bug "Bug 9842771 - Wrong SREADTIM and MREADTIM statistics in AUX_STATS$".  See [this link](http://structureddata.org/2008/01/02/what-are-your-system-statistics/) for realistic statistics and an example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to tell the optimizer to forget about indexes

```
 SELECT /*+NO_INDEX(dog_statuses)*/ *
 FROM dog_statuses
```